# Is there a way to import functions from one python file to another?

Tags: python

I would like to organise my code into files using modules in python. I then want to import the module that contains those functions into another file so I can more easily edit code in the future .

I'm using an app called pycharm to code and all files mentioned in this are held in the same larger file.

First I tried this...

first file: converters.py

```
def metres_to_feet(length):
    return length * 3.28


def feet_to_metres(length):
    return length / 3.28
```

I would like to import this function into another file called Helloworld - youtube.py
To do this I tried this...

second file: Helloworld - youtube.py

```
import converters

print(converters.metres_to_feet(100))
```

After inputting this code I got this error code below.

```
  print(converters.metres_to_feet(100))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'converters' has no attribute 'metres_to_feet'
```

Next I tried to import a specific function from converters.py...

```
from converters import metres_to_feet

metres_to_feet(100)
```

This resulted in the error below...

```
from converters import metres_to_feet
ImportError: cannot import name 'metres_to_feet' from 'converters'
```

Comment: Are both files in the same directory?

Comment: yes both files are in the same directory

Comment: That should work, any chance you have a library called converters? What do you get if you do `converters.__dir__()`? (After importing converters)

Comment: There must have been an issue with the files as I've made a new project and tried it again which worked so thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

I hope everything worked out fine for you. I just wanted to point out a few things that may help you out later. Firstly, your naming scheme, you’ve named your second python file as `Helloworld - youtube.py`. Here I’d recommend that you start following a naming convention like Snake (`helloworld_youtube.py`) or Camel case (`helloworldYoutube.py`) which are most common. Secondly, i’d recommend not adding all of your file into the same directory. This is because when you get into larger project, managing multiple files will become a hassle. Therefore I’d suggest that you start putting support files in folders. For example, for your project leave your main file in the root directory, then add all your supporting files in a separate support folder. Your folder directory would look something like this:

```
Project
|_support
|  |_converters.py
|
|_helloworldYoutube.py
```

You could then start importing the functions like:

```
import support.converters

print(support.converters.metres_to_feet(100)) 
# 328.0
```

Or:

```
import support.converters as myfuncs

print(myfuncs.metres_to_feet(100)) 
# 328.0
```

Or your could simply use an * to import everything as they are:

```
from support.converters import *

print(metres_to_feet(100))
# 328.0
```